# Adding transition effect to my css

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following

HTML

```
<div id="left_nav_wrapper">

   <div class="sidebar_wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar_header">Header</div>
      <div class="sidebar_content">Content</div>
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar_wrapper">
       <div class="sidebar_header">Header</div>
       <div class="sidebar_content">Content</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar_wrapper { width: 150px;  }
.sidebar_header { width: 150px; background-color: #F18986;  }
.sidebar_content { display: none; width: 150px; margin-left: -150px; background-color: #444; }
.sidebar_header:hover + .sidebar_content { display: inherit; margin-left: 0px; }
```

I want when they hover over the header, the content shows (which I have done) now I want to add a transition so it slides in, when I

```
add transition: all 1s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
```

to the css it does not do anything, I have added it to the .sidebar_header and .sidebar_content and can not figure out why it will not use the transition when appearing.

Any help would be appreciated THANKS!

Comment: check this, he is using opacity, display doesn't work with transitions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions do not work on display property. You have to set properties like height: 0 to 100px like i have done here.

```
.sidebar_content {
    height: 0;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    background-color: #444;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
}

.sidebar_header:hover + .sidebar_content {
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

You cannot transition to height auto. In the case you don't want to fix the height of sidebar_content

You have to do transition on max-height property by setting it to a very high value that it never reaches. But it do have its consequences. You will have to adjust the transition duration to remove the delay when the max-height transitions from 0 to that high value.

As the maximum value of the max-height increases your reverse transition will be delayed

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `display: none;` from `.sidebar_content` as your transition will not have an effect on it.
2. Use `height: 0` to hide the element, as setting it to `display: none` will disable the transition.
3. Set `.sidebar_wrapper` to `overflow: hidden` to hide the portion of the `.sidebar_content` that hasn't reached the final position.

**CSS**

```
.sidebar_wrapper { width: 150px;  }
.sidebar_header { width: 150px; background-color: #F18986; overflow: hidden; }
.sidebar_content { height: 0; width: 150px; background-color: #444; margin-left: -150px;
transition: all 1s linear; -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; }
.sidebar_header:hover + .sidebar_content { height: auto; margin-left: 0px; }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MLPLs/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use transition with this. However you can use animation of CSS3 with this :

```
sidebar_header:hover + .sidebar_content 
{
    display: block;
    animation: fadein 2s;  
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;   
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein
{  
   from   {opacity:0;}
   to {opacity:1;margin-left:0;}
}

@keyframes fadein
{  
   from   {opacity:0;}
   to {opacity:1;margin-left:0;}
}
```

the animation-fill-mode = *the target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution*

This way you can still use display: none; to completely get rid of the element.

Here a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uU2TV/).**

Answer (score 0):

`transition` do not work for `display`, you must do like this:

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/DYVVv/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="left_nav_wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar_wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar_header">Header</div>
    <div class="sidebar_content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar_wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar_header">Header</div>
    <div class="sidebar_content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar_wrapper {
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar_header {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #F18986;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3
}
.sidebar_content {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #444;
}
.sidebar_header:hover + .sidebar_content {
    display: inherit;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```