# How to add a transition in CSS and HTML when I click an icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

When I want to click the icon on a phone to open the menu I want there to be a transition. This is the code for responsive devices:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    nav {
      height: 80px;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  .logo {
      padding-left: 50px;
      margin: 0;
      width: 20%;

    }
  ul {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      width: 80%;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 70px 0 0;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
  span.nav-toggle {
      display: none;
    }

    


   
  }
```

I was expecting nothing because I did not know how to do that. I tried many things but I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: You haven't added any `transition` statements to your CSS

Comment: Use a JavaScript click handler that adds a class to the menu, and use `transition` in the style of that class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding transition effect to my css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230611/adding-transition-effect-to-my-css)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.

Comment: Can you add your html so I can view the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi in your CSS ist a little mistake, you cant give a `transition` to disply propperties. `display: none/block, flex` etc. are instand. If you want to build a Navi with `transition` you should use the `height`, thats the simplest way.

```
.navNormal{
      width: 15rem;
      height: 0;
}
.navTransition{
      height: 10rem;
      line-height: 4rem;
      transition:height 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

To trigger the animation you can use a `Checkbox` if you want to use CSS only.
Otherwise you can use the `onClick/onclick` Attibute, an `addEventListener` (JS without Framework) or command `classList.toggle(navTransition)`